# En tkinter, como colocar correctamente un vscroll en un widget Text

Tags: python, tkinter

de vuelta. Estoy intentando colocar en un Text (tSalida) un vscroll, pero cuando lo coloco, el Text no me coje el tamaño que debe de tener, y se adapta el scroll, o sease, al reves.

```
class App (ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        Servidor = '127.0.0.1'
                
        self.lblAhora = tk.Label(self.master, font=('Arial',12),bg="lightblue")
        self.lblAhora.place(x=10,y=10)
        
        self.lblS = tk.Label(self.master,text='Servidor:',bg="lightblue")
        self.lblS.place(x=530,y=10)

        self.tSalida = tk.Text(self.master,width=108,height=20,wrap="word", bg="lightblue",font=("Courier New",9))
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tSalida,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.tSalida.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set,wrap=tk.NONE)
        self.tSalida.tag_configure("Apagado", foreground="red")
        self.tSalida.tag_configure("Encendido", foreground="blue")
        self.tSalida.tag_configure('texto',foreground='black')
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.tSalida.place(x=10,y=40)

        H = datetime.now().strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

        self.cuadro1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.master,width=100,height=200,text = 'Estado',background="#2F539B")
        self.Estado = tk.StringVar()
        self.Estado.set("Apagado")
        # Crear los Radiobutton y asociarlos a la misma variable
        self.radio1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.cuadro1, width=10,anchor=tk.W, text="Encendido", variable=self.Estado, value="Encendido",command=self.Cambiar_ON_OFF,background="#2F539B")
        self.radio2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.cuadro1, width=10,anchor=tk.W, text="Apagado", variable=self.Estado, value="Apagado",command=self.Cambiar_ON_OFF,background="#2F539B")
        # Posicionar los Radiobutton en la ventana
        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.cuadro1.place(x=670,y=350)
                       
        self.MostrarHora()
        self.tSalida.insert(tk.END, self.Ahora()+f'Estado: {self.Estado.get()}\n')
        
        self.tSalida2 = tk.Text(self.master,width=108,height=13, bg="lightyellow",font=("Courier New",8))
        self.tSalida2.place(x=10,y=440)        

    def salir(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def MostrarHora(self):
        pass
                
    def Cambiar_ON_OFF(self):
        pass

    def Ahora(self):
        return datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S ")
    
    def Llamar_config(self):
        pass
```

Más tarde lo quiero tambien colocar en el tSalida2, aunque con este widget tuve otros inconvenientes, pero eso es para mas tarde.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de agregar la Scrollbar como hija del widget Text, lo que debes hacer es crear un Frame que actúe como contenedor de ambos y usar `pack` para posicionarlos uno al lado del otro. Luego posicionas el frame tal como hacías con el Text antes.

Ademas, debes configurar la Scrollbar para que al desplazarla se desplace el contendido del Text también.

Un ejemplo simplificado basado en tu código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App (ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        
        # Creamos el Frame contenedor, el Text y su ScrollBar
        self.salida_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.text_salida = tk.Text(
            self.salida_frame,
            width=108,
            height=20,
            wrap="word",
            bg="lightblue",
            font=("Courier New", 9)
        )
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.salida_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        
        # Configuramos el Text y la ScrollBar para que se sincronicen
        self.text_salida.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text_salida.yview)
        
        # Posicionamos el Text y su ScrollBar en el frame contenedor
        self.text_salida.pack(side="left")
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.salida_frame.place(x=10, y=40)
        
        # Solo algun texto para ver que funciona
        self.text_salida.insert(tk.END, "\n".join(f'{"#" * n}' for n in range(109)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root, width=1000, height=400).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

No tiene nada que ver, pero te recomiendo que te mires las [convenciones de estilo en Python (PEP-8)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), especialmente las referidas al nombre de las variables, clases, métodos/funciones, etc. No es algo obligatorio, pero hace el código mucho mas fácil de leer, de depurar y de mantener por otros desarrolladores

Comment: Adaptando el código... y tomo nota de la recomendación.

Comment: Despues de poner el código, lo único que me hace es redimensionar el master al tamaño del text (tSalida), si lo redimensiono manualmente, aparecen los demas controles y el tSalida se me va centrando en el master, ademas el vscrollbar se me muestra en el master, arriba a la izquierda. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola Jose, el Text y el Scroll si no te aparecen juntos seguramente estas posicionandolos mal a ellos y a su frame contenedor. Sin conocer como tienes el código ahora pueden ser mil cosas, seria bueno que editaras la pregunta y agregaras el codigo actual a lo que ya hay (sin eliminar el contenido actual de la pregunta, que si no queda todo sin contexto).  Lo ideal es que agregues el código mínimo que muestre el problema que comentas pero que sea funcional, es decir que pueda ser ejecutado por nosotros para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: Un comentario aparte, posicionar widgets con place de forma absoluta es una mala idea a no ser que estés plenamente seguro de que esa app se va a ejecutar en un entorno muy restringido y controlado. El principal problema es que se vera todo bien en tu PC pero si se ejecuta con dispositivos con resoluciones distintas todo puede quedar descuadrado incluso dejar la app inusable. Generalmente usar pack/grid o posicionar dinamicamente  usando posiciones relativas en función del tamaño de la ventana es mas adecuado.

Comment: Gracias. Si, el código no va a salir de mi pc, estoy aprendiendo y es para ello, pero tomo nota.  El código es el mismo al que me ayudastes para cambiar el color de apagado/encendido, pero edito y pego el código.

Comment: De nuevo gracias. Despues de "marear" el código y la ayuda de FJSevilla, comprendí el funcionamiento y pude ponerlo tambien, en otro widget. Hasta el próximo problema.